# when i click the drive shoing opwn with window dialog box

Tags: windows-xp

When i click the c-drive it is now opening , instead it showing the dialog box,

please check the screen shot ,

When i click the c-drive it opening like this screen shot

[image-url](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?bf2f3c56e5.jpg)

Comment: @thelost: "Local Disk (C:)" Nope, definitely not a removable drive.

Comment: tried restarting your PC (since it's a M$ OS that's always an option) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I googled a bit and was able to find
[this](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/223/1/Open-With-dialog-appears-when-double-clicking-on-a-mapped-network-drive-in-My-Computer.html).

You should also try opening the drive by clicking Explore in the context menu and see if there is an autorun.inf file that you could have copied by accident. It's probably going to be a hidden one, and maybe even a protected one, so check your Folder Option to make sure it shows all files. Although, that does sounds like something a virus would do.

Comment: i remove one extension from regedit...now roblem fixed...somthing started with m.....